# Highcharts $.ajax() in jQuery - pie chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, charts, highcharts

I'm new to Highcharts and all of the help from here and some research has got me to my current status using Highcharts in my project. I'm still having an issue, the pie chart isn't loading data retrieved using $.ajax(). I have no idea what to try next. Any direction or help is much appreciated.

I'm getting data from MS SQL and using $.ajax().

I want to replicate what I made here: http://jsfiddle.net/bvaxmcLr/, but with my data from SQL. I can see the data on the page, but I can't get the chart to show. All of my code is below. Does anyone have any suggestions/ideas? Thanks!

**JavaScript file**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var options = {

    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        type: 'pie',
        options3d: {
            enabled: true,
            alpha: 45
        }
    },
    title: {
        text: null
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: null
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.y:.1f}</b>'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            colors: ['#739600', '#bb0826', '#fcc60A'],
            size: '100%',
            //innerSize: 100,
            depth: 45,
            allowPointSelect: true,
            cursor: 'pointer',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false
            },
            showInLegend: true
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Amount',
        data: []
    }]
}

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../../WebServices/ORM-CV-Service.asmx/fetch_A1ACicat",
    data: {},
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    async: true,
    success: OnSuccess,
    error: OnError
});

function OnSuccess(data) {

    $.each(data.d, function (key, value) {

        options.series[0].data.push([value.Status_Color, value.Corrective_Action_ID]);
        alert(value.Status_Color);
        alert(value.Corrective_Action_ID);
        //$("#ulItem").append("<ul>" + value.Status_Color + value.Corrective_Action_ID + "</ul>");

    })

    chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);

}
function OnError(data) {
    alert('fail');
}});
```

**HTML file**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Pie Chart Example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-3d.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The AJAX call is succeeding?  In `OnSuccess` what's the output of console.log(data.d)?  My WAG is that `Corrective_Action_ID` is being returned as a string not an int.

Comment: It succeeds, but I get a weird chart to show. I added {} to the data part of the series... data: [{}] and it makes a pie chart, but its adding an extra slice to the front. i have 2 items pulling from the db, but showing 3 on the chart, with the first one being empty with no data, but shows a slice.

Comment: The output from the console is Array [ Object, Object ]

Comment: The json is the same as you have in jsfiddle?

Comment: I have a question on [highcharts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77239291/6854117) can you please see it?