# Yii2 unable to view column chart using highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am trying to plot a chart via highchart in yii2. I have already installed it and set it. Below is my code in my `index.php` view

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
function loadChartData() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '$url_chart', 
        method: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            // Extract data into arrays
            var categories = [];
            var totalConnections = [];
            var surveysDone = [];

            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                categories.push(data[i].sub_division);
                totalConnections.push(data[i].total_connections);
                surveysDone.push(data[i].surveys_done);
            }
            console.log(categories)
            // Initialize Highcharts with retrieved data
           Highcharts.chart('chart-container', {
chart: {
    type: 'column'
},
title: {
    text: 'Sub-Division Wise Survey Count and Connections'
},
xAxis: {
    categories: categories,
    title: {
        text: 'Sub-Division'
    }
},
yAxis: {
    title: {
        text: 'Count'
    }
},
tooltip: {
    formatter: function () {
        return 'Sub-Division: <b>' + this.x + '</b><br>' +
            'Total Connections: <b>' + totalConnections[this.point.index] + '</b><br>' +
            'Surveys Done: <b>' + surveysDone[this.point.index] + '</b>';
    }
},
plotOptions: { // Add plotOptions here
    column: {
        pointPadding: 0.2,
        borderWidth: 0,
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            inside: true,
            color: 'red',
            style: {
                fontWeight: 'bold'
            },
            formatter: function () {
                return this.y;
            }
        }
    }
},
series: [{
    name: 'Total Survey Done',
    data: surveysDone
}]
});
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('An error occurred while loading the chart data.');
        }
    });
}
```

**Output**

[image]

The chart does show the x and y-axis but doesn't show the data(columns) in it.

Also, I am not getting any errors on the console.

**Update 1**

I have added the below code inside my highchart

```
  events: {
    load: function () {
        console.log('Chart loaded successfully');
    }
},
```

But log doesn't shows me this message

**Update 2**

Here is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1wgudyr4/2/)

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Check How `surveysDone` variable looks in console? Does it compatible with Series parameter?

Comment: @InsaneSkull the data in console is like this (85) ['0', '166', '169', '0', '340', '113', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '708', '1003', '302', '269', '282', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '144', '162', '128', '127', '128', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '73', '17', '10', '100', '403', '324', '356', '198', '371', '150', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '147', '189', '275', '206', '287', '147', '175', '0', '90', '134', '121', '0']

Comment: The categories  are (85) ['SANDA', 'GULSHAN-E-RAVI', 'NAWANKOT', 'BUND ROAD', 'DHOLANWAL', ..... ]

Comment: The total connections are (85) ['2', '184', '169', '8', '340', '113', '185', '210', '71', '252', '272', '356', '5', '4', '500', '392', '1431', '135', '478', '90', '809', '1085', '303', '270', '282', '508', '609', '304', '521', '550', '217', '57', '177', '170', '96', '144', '189', '212', '151', '250', '21', '212', '68', '144', '124', '114', '137', '73', '110', '108', '240', '63', '132', '116', '142', '208', '188', '187', '73', '17', '59', '122', '754', '351', '1286', '973', '825', '151', '148', '998', '468', '152', '486', '149', '271', '275', '206', '377', '147', '175', '1297', '644', '238',..]

Comment: @InsaneSkull I have also added the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1wgudyr4/2/) you can see it

Comment: `var totalConnections = [2, 184, 169, 8];
and  var surveysDone = [0, 166, 169, 0];` It's string vs integer issue as i suspected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date should be given as a `number`, not a `string`. And `console.log()` is not called because `events.load` should be in the `chart`.

```js
var categories = ['SANDA', 'GULSHAN-E-RAVI', 'NAWANKOT', 'SHAD BAGH'];
var surveysDone = [0, 166, 169, 0];

Highcharts.chart('chart-container', {
 chart: {
   type: 'column',
   events: {
     load: function() {
       console.log('Chart loaded successfully');
     }
   }
 },
 xAxis: {
   categories: categories,
 },
 series: [{
   data: surveysDone
 }]
});
```

**Demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/0u8v5b1L/ 
**API**: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load

Comment: Yes that's was the issue

Answer (score 0):

Hi first of all check error log in respective directory.

e.g.

backend\runtime\logs
frontend\runtime\logs

you need to pass data in those format which allow by chart.